# How to fix the read ECONNRESET at request ( with newman tool)

Tags: rest, api, postman, newman

I am trying to execute the POSTMAN collection with multiple requests using the NEWMAN CLI tool.

All the requests in the collections are executed successfully with postman but when i execute with newman tool it's failed and it show an error as 'read ECONNRESET' at request (please help me how to fix it ) 
[image: Newman eroor]

Comment: 1) What version of Newman are you using? 2) Are you using Newman docker container? 3) Which Node version installed on your system?

Comment: @Div thanks for the reply i am using all the latest versions of node and newman . After all i find out that i have certificate .pfx in postman when i executed scripts and it worked fine . I need to know how to pass the .pfx certificate file in newman CLI. i am not sure how to do this ?

Comment: Alright. You can all the newman commands [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman#ssl-client-certificates)

Comment: @Div i was having issues with using a command SSL Certificate (pfx file) any suggestions u can give ? its throwing an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`newman run` option to pass the certificate:

`--ssl-client-cert`: The path to the public client certificate file.

please check the [documentation](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman#ssl-client-certificates).

Comment: Just for the clarification that when we use the .PEM certificate file we need to pass both key and password ?!